# How to get nested table column?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

For example, how to do something like this:

```
create type nums_list as table of number;

declare 
  nnn nums_list := nums_list(2,3,4,1);
begin
   for i in ( select col from table(nnn) order by col ) 
   loop
     dbms_output.put_line( col );
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Do you mean the  column _name_? Can you clarify exactly what you're after?

Comment: Like what do you mean?

Comment: @ Ben, Yes, I mean column name, I need instead of `select * from table(nested table)...` get column name (alias) from nested table: `select column_name from table(nested table)...`.

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov, Thanks very much, why you remove your very helpful comment? `COLUMN_VALUE` pseudocolumn was exactly what needed.

Comment: Nested tables(a.k.a virtual tables) have only one pseudo `column - column_value`. There is no col or any other column name for that matter. So, if there is a need to drop the asterisk and explicitly reference that single column a virtual table returns you use `column_value` [like so](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5543/2). P.S. `why you remove your very helpful comment?` Sorry, did this accidentally.